# geom_pointrange y-axis negative value ordering

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am attempting to create a dot and CI plot using results from different regression results.
I created a dataframe that contains the betas, lower limit, upper limit, and some grouping variable.

some sample data:

```
count <- 1:8

race  <- c(rep(c("Black","Non-Black"),4))

betas <- c(0.97,-0.63,
           0.77,-0.07,
           0.07,-0.07,
           0.16,-0.46)

lower <- c(-0.41,-2.16,
            0.29,-0.58,
           -0.44,-0.64,
           -0.45,-1.22)
           
upper <- c(2.36,0.89,
           1.25, 0.45,
           0.59,0.49,
           0.78,0.3)

plot4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(count,race,outcome,betas,lower,upper))
```

Using the following code

```
ggplot(plot4, aes(x=reorder(count, sort(as.numeric(count))), 
                  y=betas, 
                  group=outcome,
                  color=race))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper))+
  theme_classic()
```

results in a Y-axis that is "out of order":
[image: plot_example]

Negative fractions are plotted as "smaller" (further from zero) than negative integers and the intervals do not contain the value they were created from.

I would like to fix the issue so that the y-axis goes from the most negative (e.g.-2.16) to the most positive (e.g. 2.36)

I tried re-ordering the y-axis as I did with the x-axis but that didn't help.

I'm also not convinced that this is the best way to present the data so really any advice or fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From experience, it seems that your `y` variable is a character or factor, whereas you'd expect it to be numeric. Try constructing a data.frame in the usual way `data.frame(count, ...)` instead of the `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` approach, which converts it to a character matrix first.

Comment: I checked the class of each variable and they were all numeric. But you were right, constructing the data frame without `cbind` did the trick. Thank you, so much!